# Does Threads in activity terminates when starting another?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, back, terminate

I have an activity that starts 3 threads that make a 
"While(true)" loop

when i start a new activity, does those threads terminate themselves?

And another question, how do i start a new activity but i don't want to allow
the 'back' button to return me to the old activity -
actually i want to dispose the first activity and create and show a new one

thank you
Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i start a new activity, does those threads terminate themselves?

No, they don't. You have to stop them before closing your activity.

> how do i start a new activity but i don't want to allow the 'back' button to return me to the old activity

Just call finish() from your first activity when you start the second one :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: please note that your activity might not finish completely if something still holds its context. So if you call something with "this" parameter from your activity, make sure that context is nulled or your activity will still exists in the memory but appear to be finished. Can cause ugly side effects

Answer (score 0):

When activity pauses or stops Threads might not be stopped immediately. Better strategy is to have a flag which is set to false as soon as onPause or stop is called.
Threads check for this flag and interrupt themselves or come out of run method.

If you don't want back button to show older Activity, you can use NO_HISTORY flag for the older activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

If you want to have this activity as the first activity in the stack use this flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME

Comment: If your activity only stops or pauses your threads are not stopped or paused just because of this.